# react router with url from server not matching root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an express server set up that redirects a user to the following url.

`http://localhost:3000/#/user/access_token=***refresh_token=***`

The issue I am having is that it cannot find the route on the front end.

The express code looks like this

```
res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/#/user/' +
   querystring.stringify({
      access_token: access_token,
      refresh_token: refresh_token
}));
```

Then on the react side my code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import Home from './Home';
import Address from './User';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path="/user/:access_token/:refresh_token" component={User} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> browser.js:49Warning: [react-router] Location
>   "/user/access_token=xxx&refresh_token=xxx" did not match any routes

Comment: Should the path be `path="/user?access_token=:access_token&refresh_token=:refresh_token"`?

Comment: @MattMokary same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As React Router docs say you don't need to specify query params in your route path definitions: [Official Example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/query-params/app.js#L22)

1) So if your link is like this:

> http://localhost:3000/#/user/access_token?refresh_token=123456

then your route should be like this:

```js
<Route path="/user/access_token" component={User} />
```

2) If your link is like this:

> http://localhost:3000/#/user?access_token=:access_token&refresh_token=:refres‌​h

then your route should be like this:

```js
<Route path="/user" component={User} />
```

Comment: Also, need to start the query parameter string with a `?` and not a `/` like it is now. `'http://localhost:3000/#/user/' + ...` should be `'http://localhost:3000/#/user?' + ...`